# Estimating fractal dimension of two dimensional data in R

Tags: r, clustering

I am trying to estimate the fractal dimension of a list of coordinates, such as:

```
          X1        X2
1  0.6073672 0.6663980
2  0.6837522 0.6080113
3  0.5109583 0.6071990
4  0.4456634 0.2165213
5  0.6773562 0.6667185
6  0.6593706 0.6774323
7  0.5778927 0.7234859
8  0.3655071 0.3496862
9  0.4694057 0.2875728
10 0.4258961 0.4424538
```

I was hoping to use a package like fractaldim, but it seems that I can not pass my data since it is not a square matrix.

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?

Background: I am trying to calculate clusters using the fractal dimension (see "Using Self-Similarity to Cluster Large Data Sets" http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=635431.635447)

My Data looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ask the same question in [Matrix,Estimate the fractal dimension of two dimensional data in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40558438/estimate-the-fractal-dimension-of-two-dimensional-data-in-r)

> I was hoping to use a package like fractaldim, but it seems that I can not pass my data since it is not a square matrix.

```
x = c(0.6073672, 0.6837522, 0.5109583, 0.4456634, 0.6773562, 0.6593706, 0.5778927, 0.3655071, 0.4694057, 0.4258961)
y = c(0.666398, 0.6080113, 0.607199, 0.2165213, 0.6667185, 0.6774323, 0.7234859, 0.3496862, 0.2875728, 0.4424538)
fd.estim.boxcount(cbind(x,y),plot.loglog=TRUE, plot.allpoints=TRUE, nlags="auto")
```

[image]

```
fd.estim.squareincr (cbind(x,y), p.index = 1, plot.loglog = TRUE, plot.allpoints = TRUE)
```

[image]

And others, but I don't know what you want exactly ([How do you use R to find the box counting dimension of a two dimensional set of data, or scatter plot?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875372/how-do-you-use-r-to-find-the-box-counting-dimension-of-a-two-dimensional-set-of)) and unfortunately there are many "fractal" dimensions.

In Python, look at [Fractal Dimension and Box Counting](http://connor-johnson.com/2014/03/04/fractal-dimension-and-box-counting/) or [Fractal Dimension Computation in Python Code](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2000-September/053171.html)

### New

In fractaldim

> Implements various methods for estimating fractal dimension of time series **and** 2 dimensional data.

In each example, there is a command with `# 1d time series` and  `# 2d random fields`

```
# for 2d random fields
fd2d = fd.estim.boxcount(cbind(x,y),plot.loglog=TRUE, plot.allpoints=TRUE, nlags="auto")
fd2d['fd'] # fractal dimension
$fd
[1] 1.295456
```

The problem is that you must understand the various parameters of the library.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry but `fd.estim.boxcount` is indeed for timeseries data only, as it is clearly depicted in the package help file.

You can test this by changing the order of the lines in the x,y vectors and checking the results:

```
x = c(0.6073672, 0.6837522, 0.5109583, 0.4456634, 0.6773562, 0.6593706, 0.5778927, 0.3655071, 0.4694057, 0.4258961)
y = c(0.666398, 0.6080113, 0.607199, 0.2165213, 0.6667185, 0.6774323, 0.7234859, 0.3496862, 0.2875728, 0.4424538)

ordr <- sample(seq_along(x)); fd.estim.boxcount(cbind(x[ordr], y[ordr]))$fd
# [1] 1.725825
ordr <- sample(seq_along(x)); fd.estim.boxcount(cbind(x[ordr], y[ordr]))$fd
# [1] 1.347923
```

I think we can agree that fractal dimensionality should not change depending on the order of the values processed.